# extracting lag features of numpy array (+ expand dimension) | reshape numpy array with stride=1

Tags: numpy, time-series, lag

I have a time series data array of shape `(#timestamp,#features)`. I would like to extract for each row (`timestamp`) `n_lags` (previous rows) and reshape the array such that I have the shape **`(#samples, #lags+now,#features)`** for an input to a LSTM layer of Keras.

Consider this toy example:

```
import numpy as np
n_rows = 6
n_feat= 3
n_lag = 2

a = np.array(range(n_rows*n_feat)).reshape(n_rows, n_feat)

>>> a.shape = (6, 3)
>>> a = array([[ 0,  1,  2],
           [ 3,  4,  5],
           [ 6,  7,  8],
           [ 9, 10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14],
           [15, 16, 17]])
```

With **iterating over rows** I achieve the **expected output**:

```
b = np.empty(shape=(0, (n_lag + 1), n_feat))
for idx, row in enumerate(a):
   temp = np.expand_dims(a[max(0, idx-n_lag):idx+1, :], 0)
   if temp.shape[1:] == b.shape[1:]:
       b = np.append(b, temp, axis=0)


>>> b.shape = (4, 3, 3)
>>> b = array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
            [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
            [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

           [[ 3.,  4.,  5.],
            [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
            [ 9., 10., 11.]],

           [[ 6.,  7.,  8.],
            [ 9., 10., 11.],
            [12., 13., 14.]],

           [[ 9., 10., 11.],
            [12., 13., 14.],
            [15., 16., 17.]]])
```

*Note:* the first `n_lags-1` rows do not have enough data and will be discarded in the final output

**Question:**
I would like to know if there is a **more elegant / nice** way than iterating over the rows.

Comment: Not a `keras` or `lstm` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: as this question aims to format the data according to ``keras`` ``lstm``, I anticipated that some people would find it interesting to see the connection. Never intended to spam tags but thanks for editing the tags to the guideline!

Comment: No problem; for the future, please keep in mind that tags should be only about the *content* of the question, not its (general) context.

Comment: Just a minor comment on the code. ```np.array(range(n_rows*n_feat))``` can be replaced with ```np.arange(n_rows*n_feat)```. No need to use primitive python generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new [np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) for this

```py
n_rows = 6
n_feat= 3
n_lag = 2

a = np.array(range(n_rows*n_feat)).reshape(n_rows, n_feat)

b = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(a, window_shape=(n_feat, n_feat))
b
```

output:

```
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8]]],


       [[[ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8],
         [ 9, 10, 11]]],


       [[[ 6,  7,  8],
         [ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14]]],


       [[[ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]]]])
```

`b` will just change the shape and strides of `a`, so it will contain the same memory location of `a` multiple times. In other words, no need to allocate a new array.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Many Thanks! Pretty new method though, had to update Numpy first :)