# How can I create lagged features for sklearn time series forecasting without using any more RAM?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I have 8 features but need 180 lags of each one.

My raw data easily fits in RAM (under 1gb).

When I add the lags in a naive way, it rapidly runs out of RAM.

Given that the lags are just copies of the data, how can I provide a view-like structure to sklearn that doesn’t end up deep-copying?

Comment: I would suggest the use of [`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66869172/extracting-lag-features-of-numpy-array-expand-dimension-reshape-numpy-arra) to extract lags from an array without increasing memory use, but without knowing what kind of sklearn model you're using, there's no guarantee that it doesn't call `np.ascontiguousarray()` somewhere inside sklearn.

Comment: PS: Have you considered the use of models that natively support lags, e.g. ARIMA?

Comment: @NickODell I'm trying to use ExtraTreesClassifier specifically. I've tried various forms of `stride` adjustment (although not `sliding_window`). I don't think it's possible to create a `view` of the underlying ndarray with the lags (`hstack`-ing the arrays causes a copy).

I'm going to try and pop open the source for ExtraTrees and see if it materialises the whole array. If not, I was thinking to overload the index functions of ndarray.